# How to rename pandas columns after reading CSV File

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following file:

https://dzbqqjpt.labs.coursera.org/notebooks/assignments/assignment3/assets/Energy%20Indicators.xls

And I am reading it like this, skipping headers and footer rows

```
Energy = pd.read_excel('assets/Energy Indicators.xls', header=None, sheet_name='Energy', skiprows=18, skip_footer=38
                       )  

Energy.rename(columns={Energy.columns[2]:'Country'})
Energy.rename(columns={Energy.columns[3]:'Energy Supply'})
Energy.rename(columns={Energy.columns[4]:'Energy Supply per Capita'})
Energy.rename(columns={Energy.columns[5]:'% Renewable'})


print(Energy)
```

When I print it, I get this output:

```
   0                          1                          2     3    4  \
0   NaN                Afghanistan                Afghanistan   321   10   
1   NaN                    Albania                    Albania   102   35   
2   NaN                    Algeria                    Algeria  1959   51   
3   NaN             American Samoa             American Samoa   ...  ...   
4   NaN                    Andorra                    Andorra     9  121   
..   ..                        ...                        ...   ...  ...   
222 NaN                   Viet Nam                   Viet Nam  2554   28   
223 NaN  Wallis and Futuna Islands  Wallis and Futuna Islands     0   26   
224 NaN                      Yemen                      Yemen   344   13   
225 NaN                     Zambia                     Zambia   400   26   
226 NaN                   Zimbabwe                   Zimbabwe   480   32   

              5  
0     78.669280  
1    100.000000  
2      0.551010  
3      0.641026  
4     88.695650  
..          ...  
222   45.321520  
223    0.000000  
224    0.000000  
225   99.714670  
226   52.536120  

[227 rows x 6 columns]
```

so I d-ont understand why the renaming of the columns is not working, and its still printing 6 columns and it should be 4 only.

Comment: Assign back like `Energy = Energy.rename(columns={Energy.columns[2]:'Country'})` or use `Energy.rename(columns={Energy.columns[2]:'Country'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: why do you close questions, even without reading the question?! the duplicate is totally different question

Comment: So sorry, added better dupe